# Which Windows Service is required for PowerPoint Online Presentation? [Office Presentation Service]

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-powerpoint, remote, windows-services, presentations

I need to present a PowerPoint presentation to a remote audience (without any additional software being required on the client) so I'm trying to check out [PowerPoint's **Online Presentation feature**](https://docs.microsoft.com/office365/servicedescriptions/office-online-service-description/office-online-service-description#powerpoint) (Office 365, Windows 7).

However, when I try to [broadcast](https://support.office.com/article/broadcast-your-powerpoint-presentation-online-to-a-remote-audience-25330108-518e-44be-a281-e3d85f784fee) (`Slide Show`→`Present Online`→`Office Presentation Service`) I'm told that a required Windows **Service** is "turned off".

**Any idea which service this might be?**  My Googling efforts returned nothing.

[image]

Comment: Any dependencies are list in the properties of the service in question.  Care to share a screenshot of that dialogue?

Comment: @Ramhound which dialog? all my services?

Answer (score 2):

The broadcast service has had its troubles.

A few people mentioned that the trick mentioned here worked for them:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/error-starting-broadcast-with-powerpoint-2010-but/91b76df3-6a1c-4ca6-95f0-bc2030383566

That's pretty old, though.  This is more recent and suggests that the service behind PPT broadcasting is dead:

https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-Microsoft-SharePoint-2013-bbbb0815-2538-4f1d-b647-1f7f6d508c93#__toc382936211

Note that the broadcast service is not the same as PowerPoint Online, which is a free PowerPoint viewer and lightweight editor for PowerPoint files. The broadcast service integrated with the viewer (an older version of it, I believe) that allowed you to control the flow of a show that your audience watched in the viewer.

Without the broadcast component or software installed, at least temporarily, on the audience PC, you may not be able to control what they see. You might need to resort to having them watch using the online version and direct them to advance slides over a phone line.  Shades of "Next slide, please."

Comment: +Thanks for the response, even if I don't "like" it.  Those links lead me to believe that "PowerPoint Broadcast" and "Office Broadcast Service" are two separate entities.  Figures, I try PPT for some one-off reason every 5 years or so and there always seems to be "something" wrong with it.. Leaving feedback in ppt with link to this page; I wonder if I'll get a response...

Comment: ...as for the *"next slide"* suggestion, the recipient may not have Office. I was looking forward to sharing a single link which required no download, that I could control remotely while talking on speakerphone.  Is there any comparable software with that kind of functionality, where the client doesn't need anything more than a website?

Comment: I don't know of anything that fits your needs exactly, but you might want to investigate the various screen sharing services like GoToMeeting, Zoom, and the like. Those are both commercial, but there are also free ones. They generally require installing at least some code on the audience end, but don't seem to trigger problems on even some fairly locked down systems.